# Unable to build Maven project due to Javadoc error?

Tags: maven, javadoc

Has anyone come across a similar Maven error as below?

I am unable to build my project due to the error below. All was working previously fine before I started working on the code.

I did not even work on the below defined interfaces and it seems to be related to Javadoc?

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-javadoc-plugin:2.9.1:jar (attach-javadocs) on project jonney-project: MavenReportException: Error while creating archive:

[ERROR] Exit code: 1 - /Users/me/Work/myProject/library/src/main/java/com/me/someInterface.java:45: warning: no @return
[ERROR] public abstract boolean searchForDevce();
[ERROR] ^
[ERROR] /Users/me/Work/myProject/src/main/java/com/me/someInterfaceAgain.java:52: warning: no @return
[ERROR] public abstract boolean selectDevice(int pos);
[ERROR] ^
```

Answer (score 132, accepted):

I'm guessing you switched to Java 8. In this version Javadoc is stricter on the requirements.

You have three choices:

1. Fix the errors
2. disable the strict checking
3. skip Javadoc when building

To disable the strict checking, add this to your pom.xml

```
<plugins>
  <plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-javadoc-plugin</artifactId>
    <configuration>
      <additionalparam>-Xdoclint:none</additionalparam>
    </configuration>
  </plugin>
</plugins>
```

to skip Javadoc while building, use this:

```
mvn -Dmaven.javadoc.skip=true verify
```

[Further Information](http://blog.joda.org/2014/02/turning-off-doclint-in-jdk-8-javadoc.html)

Comment: This does not work with maven-javadoc-plugin version 3.0.0. I had to go back to version 3.0.0-M1 for making -Xdoclint:none work.

Comment: thank you truly. There was no way I was going to fix all the errors.

Comment: The only for me to make this work was to skip `javadoc` altogether - thanks for the tip.  Had wasted more than 1hr jumping other hoops...

Comment: Note: with maven-javadoc-plugin version *3.0.0* `<additionalparam>` has been replaced by `<additionalOptions>`

Comment: To emphasise the above comment, this answer is the wrong answer.

Answer (score 33):

With **maven-javadoc-plugin** version 3.0.0 `<additionalparam/>` has been replaced by `<additionalOptions/>`. To reduce the errors to warnings this pom.xml entry worked for me:

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-javadoc-plugin</artifactId>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>attach-javadocs</id>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>jar</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
            <configuration>
                <additionalOptions>
                    <additionalOption>-Xdoclint:none</additionalOption>
                </additionalOptions>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Comment: with maven-javadoc-plugin >= 3.0 we now have `<doclint>none</doclint>` (see [this bug report](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/MJAVADOC-387))

Answer (score 9):

UPDATE FOR THOSE WHO GOOGLED THIS BUG: 
If the project uses source/target 8, adding 8 in javadoc configuration should make the project buildable on jdk {11, 12, 13}:

```
<plugin>
<groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
<artifactId>maven-javadoc-plugin</artifactId>
<configuration>
  <source>8</source>
</configuration>
 ...
```

Answer (score 7):

Just update your pom.xml with the properties tag, given below.

```
<properties>
    <additionalparam>-Xdoclint:none</additionalparam>
</properties>
```

Comment: If you are using v3.X of the maven-javadoc-plugin, the parameter name has changed to ```additionalJOption```.  See https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-javadoc-plugin/javadoc-mojo.html#additionalJOption.

Answer (score 6):

None of the above options seemed to work for me when using version 3.2.0. Instead I noticed the [failOnError](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-javadoc-plugin/javadoc-mojo.html#failOnError) option. Setting this tags value to false seemed to do the trick for allowing my build to succeed even when there were javadoc errors.

```
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-javadoc-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${maven.javadoc.plugin.version}</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>attach-javadocs</id>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>jar</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
            <configuration>
                <failOnError>false</failOnError>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
```

This will stop the javadoc jar from being generated for the maven project. This was okay in my case as I was only wanting to build without errors during ongoing development. The other options may still allow for the javadoc jar to be generated when there are errors.

Answer (score 4):

As mentioned by @turbanoff since version 3.0.0 the maven-javadoc-plugin config setting `<additionalparam>` has been replaced by `<additionalOptions>`

So the plugin defintion in your pom.xml can look like this:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-javadoc-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.2.0</version>
    <configuration>
        <additionalOptions>-Xdoclint:none</additionalOptions>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

This configuration will still generate the warnings. So you can and should fix them in your code. But it will now no longer break the maven build.