# Have Syntax Highlighting in Markdown for Maven Site (Fluido)

Tags: maven, syntax-highlighting, maven-site-plugin, doxia

I have tried the following in my Maven project:

- Add a markdown file `content.md` with content

````
```java
int a = 4;
```
````

in `src/main/site/markdown`.

- Write a `site.xml` with content

  ```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
  <project>
    <skin>
      <groupId>org.apache.maven.skins</groupId>
      <artifactId>maven-fluido-skin</artifactId>
      <version>1.7</version>
    </skin>
    <body>

      <menu name="Dokumentation">
        <item name="Benutzerhandbuch" href="content.html" />
      </menu>
      <menu ref="reports" />

    </body>
  </project>
  ```
- Write a `pom.xml` with

  ```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
  <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">

    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>de.continentale.testsvn</groupId>
    <artifactId>site-test</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <build>
      <plugins>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-site-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.7.1</version>
          <dependencies>
            <dependency>
              <groupId>org.apache.maven.wagon</groupId>
              <artifactId>wagon-webdav-jackrabbit</artifactId>
              <version>2.6</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
              <groupId>org.apache.maven.doxia</groupId>
              <artifactId>doxia-module-xhtml</artifactId>
              <version>1.8</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
              <groupId>org.apache.maven.doxia</groupId>
              <artifactId>doxia-module-markdown</artifactId>
              <version>1.8</version>
            </dependency>
          </dependencies>
        </plugin>
      </plugins>
    </build>

  </project>
  ```

Now I get a file `content.html` from `mvn site`. In this file, the `int a = 4` is *not* syntax highlighted.

[image]

What do I need to do to get syntax highlighting?

Answer (score 2):

I couldn't get it to work with Maven either but I found a workaround: Do the highlighting client-side in Javascript with [highligh.js](https://highlightjs.org/).

Download highlight.js and place it under `src/site/resources/highlightjs.pack.js`, as well as a CSS theme, e.g. `src/site/resources/styles/atom-one-light.css`.

In your site descriptor:

```
<project>
  <body>
    <head>
      <![CDATA[
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/foundation.css" />
      <script src="highlight.pack.js"></script>
      <script>
          document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', (event) => {
            document.querySelectorAll('pre.source').forEach((block) => {
              hljs.highlightBlock(block);
            });
          });
      </script>
      ]]>
    </head>
  </body>
</project>
```

Maven generate `<pre class="source" />` blocks for code blocks so we need to tell that to highlight.js. Unfortunately Maven doesn't put a class name corresponding to the language (Java in your example) but highlight.js auto-detects languages and that works in most cases.

Comment: I tried this answer, but the script does not appear in my output. I added the following changes (for `maven-javadoc-plugin` version 3.1.1): `<additionalOptions><additionalOption>--allow-script-in-comments</additionalOption>` instead of `<additionalparam>` ([see here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23542876/unable-to-build-maven-project-due-to-javadoc-error)); prepended `{@docRoot}/` to href's. Still no luck. No more errors in building site, but no code injected in HTML. Ideas?